# How to Remove .php Extension From Url and show 404 error when user try to enter url with .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am able to remove .php extension from url but i want if user enter the url with .php extension then page should show the 404 error using .htaccess

Any Help Please

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? It's not a 404 error.

Comment: The .php URL show at least to a permanent redirect to the new URL

Comment: Also, are you using apache, nginx, or something else?

Comment: i am using wamp server

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to hide `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank-you but it's not working according to me...  check on this link [https://phpacademy.org/forum]  this is a php forum link.. when you open this link then url is coming without extension but when you type .php in the end of url then 404 error page will come

Comment: This is result of giving incomplete information in question. In which .htaccess did you place it? Most likely you have .htaccess inside `/forum/` folder also. If that is the case then let me know as rule will need to change accordingly.

Comment: you can check [www.engineersgarage.com] site. open any page and type .php or any extension in the end then the page automatic redirect to 404 error page

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions. Where did you place this .htaccess and do you have a `/forum/.htaccess` also?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a clean url i think.

Here is a link that describes things to do.

http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls

I hope this helps.